# why check for not null before closing fileoutputstream?

Tags: fileoutputstream

See the finally part for both in and out - I don't understand why it's checking for null.  If all data is consumed, wouldn't in give -1 and out give null?  in would therefore close because -1 is not null.  under what condition would one in and out be not null and why'd you want to close out when it's not null?

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class CopyBytes {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            FileInputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream out = null;

            try {
                in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
                out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
                int c;

                while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                    out.write(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

source:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to perform a method on a `null` value, an exception will be thrown. Checking for null ensures that the OutputStream has been set and exists, and that this situation won't occur.

Without closing the stream before the program terminates, you could also lose buffered data. It is always good practice to explicitly manage your resources.

Comment: "Without closing the stream before the program terminates, you could also lose buffered data. It is always good practice to explicitly manage your resources."  Are you talking losing the data in the input or the data in the output, or the data in between input and output source?  Thanks.

Comment: The data in the output. In your specific case it may apply, but if writing to a file without terminating its connection correctly you may lose data that is in the process of being written to the file. It's generally not good practice to not have clean opening and closing of files, although recent Java versions seem to try and stop this from happening as much as they can.

Comment: How do I do that? =(  Got it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main point for this is because you don't want to lock up the files if they are not closed and the reason for checking if they are null is because if one of the files was not found to begin with then it would cause an error if you are trying to close something that does not exist.